# How to open MVC 4 view page from webform.aspx page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

basically i am looking for something like this ,

i got webform.aspx page and have button there, if i click on it i need to show MVC view page

idea is i want app with webform and mvc  !

what i am trying is : 
http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc

but here i am confused about webconfig settings

please help me to get it done,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman has a good [guide on integrating MVC with a Web Form App](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx), it should take you through the steps, here it is in a nutshell:

- Run the Upgrade Wizard (open the  Visual Studio2008 Web Application
  in Visual Studio 2010)
- Create a default ASP.NET MVC application for reference (you'll throw it away later)
- Use a differencing tool like [Beyond Compare](http://scootersoftware.com/) to integrate the new web.config entries from the ASP.NET MVC sections into the upgraded ASP.NET WebForms application