# How to open aspx file inside View Folder for MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

Ive got an aspx file, containing report viewer and im trying to open the file using controller. If i put the file in the root, it works using redirect but if i placed it in the Views folder, it wont open. Appreciate any help and thank you in advanced for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/Views` directory has a directory-specific `Web.config` file that adds a rule that prevents all direct-access to files in that directory tree.

To serve WebForms pages in an MVC project you need to move it to another directory that lacks the `Web.config` rule (e.g. `~/Content`), or disable the rule (not recommended).

Your `.aspx` file doesn't belong in the `~/Views` directory anyway as it is not a *View* (in the MVC architecture) - it's a "page" :)

Note that your project will not work in ASP.NET Core as support for WebForms has been removed in that version.

Comment: ooo.. so theres no way to place aspx file inside View folder is it? i can only placed it in the root or outside the View folder?

Comment: @ArifSam Generally, yes. But why is that a problem? You sound disappointed.

Comment: hahah. Ive just started learning MVC and i thought that i can deliver my report in a purely MVC way to my supervisor. A bit disappointed i suppose. lol

Comment: another question if you dont mind answering, how do i go back to mvc view from aspx page? <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li> using this wont work inside aspx page right?

Comment: @ArifSam not necessarily. It might still be possible to use URL Routing, but you won't be able to use `UrlHelper`. I don't know how your project (or webserver) is configured so I cannot help you further.

Comment: which part do you need? Im quite at lost here as not much reference ive found on google. The only question that is the same as mine is this, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234423/how-to-open-mvc-4-view-page-from-webform-aspx-page). If you could state the file that you need ill gladly provide it. Thank you so much again for helping. Never thought that a simple button to open another page could be difficult.

Comment: Fyi, for this project, Ive only created a web application mvc, and add webform on the root. All is left as it is, default configuration, the only thing that i did is add "return Redirect("~/ReportWebForm.aspx")" to Home controller ActionResult to open aspx file.

Comment: @ArifSam Please post a new StackOverflow question for this separate ASPX-to-MVC linking issue.

Comment: Done. [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609293/how-to-open-mvc5-view-from-aspx-page) Thanks again.