# How to open MVC5 view from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Ive got an aspx file on the root of web application MVC5 project. I can go from Mvc View to the aspx file but im stuck on **going back to mvc view**. How do i go back **from button event in Aspx**? Fyi, this is just an empty project as im trying to learn on MVC. So everything is left as it is. Default configuration. The only difference that ive made is add redirect to the aspx page inside Home controller ActionResult.

Folder Structure and redirect code.

[image: Folder structure and redirect code]

p/s. If you are wondering why i used an aspx file inside my mvc, im trying to do dynamic rdlc reporting using reportviewer. Im not sure if it could be done using mvc view. As far as i know, razor engine could not use reportviewer and thats why i use an aspx file. Im probably wrong on this as im still very new in doing MVC. Tqvm in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

First change your current code

```
public RedirectResult Report()
{
    return Redirect("~/ReportWebForm.aspx");
}
```

And in your .aspx page, add

```
Response.Redirect("/Controller/Action")
```

Comment: Ive tried this and error is displayed on the page. "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found". Ive read somewhere that i need to change the routeconfig? Im not familiar with this so i dont really understand much.

Comment: What is your controller and action name ? Did you changes them correctly in the above code ?

Comment: I have also changed the code a bit. Edit the right controller and action name in the above code and give it a try.

Comment: Oh my.. Now i really feel stupid. I just copy and pasted it. Really sorry for that. Yes it works very well. Thank you so much again for your help. Just a question, why do i need to use RedirectResult instead of ActionResult? Even if i use ActionResult it could still open my aspx page.

Comment: Basically both are valid syntaxes but if you use RedirectResult  it can only redirect to a url not to view or anthing. Also, RedirectResult  inherits from ActionResult `public class RedirectResult : ActionResult`.  [Check Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387127/mvc-redirectresult) for a detailed explanation

Comment: where are you supposed to put the Response.Redirect in the aspx page?

Comment: @d0rf47 : It depends, as for the questions above it should be inside the button event in Aspx.